# What determines size of the zone in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

This is not gameplay related but more about what's going on under the hood of the game.

What determines the size of the zone in Skyrim? For example, Solitude is one big zone with a lot of people in it, but every shop, however tiny it is, is a separate zone with a loading screen before you enter.

The most strange example in my opinion is Jorrvaskr. Why was the basement not made a part of it initially? What's the point in the loading screen there? There are dungeons ten times the size of it.

Comment: Because... the game was designed that way :L

Comment: go ask the creators of skyrim this question

Comment: Guys, [be nice](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7624/lets-be-nice-to-each-other) - these kinds of comments are not useful.

Answer (score 8):

Cell sizes are strictly and entirely determined by how the world designers created the cells in the game data. (What you're calling zones are called "cells" under the hood.) The engine can have arbitrarily large cells (performance issues notwithstanding), so it's really just a matter of what is convenient when designing a place.

By tradition, every interior is its own cell. That's just how Bethesda have been building NetImmerse-based games since Morrowind. Some interiors are split up into multiple cells, and this is especially common with basements for reasons I'm not 100% clear on. Probably for lighting reasons, since the ambient light is shared across a cell, and you would want a different ambient light level or colour for a windowless basement than you would the airy, many-windowed house above it.

Also traditionally, every town and city that isn't simply part of an outside worldspace is usually one cell. Again, this is likely for design simplicity, since there usually isn't an natural place to put a cell border with a loading screen between. A notable exception to this is the Imperial City in Oblivion, which has a cell per city district, but the high inner walls in that city's architecture allow for natural loading boundaries between the districts that most cities don't have.

If you want to really understand how this stuff works under the hood, you're in luck – Skyrim is one of those wonderful games that can be opened up and tinkered with using tools very similar to those used by the game designers. You can download a copy of the [Creation Kit](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Creation_Kit) through Steam (look in the Tools option in the All Games menu of the Library), and read up about how to use it and how the game is put together on the [Creation Kit Wiki](http://www.creationkit.com/).

Comment: Not to forget the fact interiors are built with fixed tiles (and other object) only, but not using any kind of heightmap (like standard overworld cells). Also by using multiple zones for one dungeon you avoid problems, e.g. if you want an air filled cave under a body of water. Also not to forget memory usage: splitting interior and basement allows you to load/use either tileset, not forcing everything at once to be kept in memory.

Comment: @Mario Interiors being built with fixed tiles is a bit of trivia that doesn't really bear on why some are small and some are large. Memory usage doesn't bear on size as a hard limit, and doesn't impact performance unless it's rather extreme. Putting an airspace under water is a good use, yes: water level, like ambient light settings, are shared across a cell, so you have to use another cell to get an air-filled space "beneath" the water level of another cell.

Answer (score -2):

I suspect that it's down to:

1. Where there are doors, that can trigger the load screens.
2. The total count of items in the zone, so low density zones can be bigger.